Pouch dB, couchbase scope and collection support
Im able to setup the couchbase server and enabled sync gateway for a bucket. However the values docs are added to _default scope and _default collection.
Upon creating a new collection inside _default scope called myCollection. I can able to save and retrieve the data using rest api's using the sync gateway public url.
When adding the database name with scope and collection in client side using pouchdb like
new pouchdb("mydb._default.myCollection").
I'm getting an error in the sync gateway console that this dB does not exist.
Is there a way in pouch db to do sync using scope and collection.
I'm trying to sync the couchbase collection using pouchdb. It's throwing database does not exits.

PouchDB does not support scopes and collections.
